# Connection problem in Win2k3 server 64 bit with JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

`DriverManager#getConnection()` returns `null` when I am deploying my JSP/Servlet package in a Windows 2003 Server environment (64 bit). The database is Microsoft SQL 2005 Enterprise Edition.

The code is:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:calsoft2k","xxx","xxx");
```

The same code is working without any problems in Windows XP (32 bit) box. I am using Apache Tomcat 6.X server in both production and development environment.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **real** JDBC driver instead of the (pardon me) *lousy* ODBC bridge driver.

Decent DB vendors supplies their own JDBC drivers. The one for SQL2005 can just be found at [microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C47053EB-3B64-4794-950D-81E1EC91C1BA&displaylang=en). This driver is however known not to be very optimal in both the performance and the level of JDBC API support. You could also consider the much faster and better [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: as always BalusC is great, now i am fan of BalusC :-)